# SpriteKit - get absolute size of SKNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgsize

I'm programming a small game in Swift and `SpriteKit`, which is made of a boxes (4 * 8).

```
Scene (1024 * 768)
    boxes (964 * 452)
        row1 (932 * 25)
            col1 (24 * 116)
            col2 (24 * 116)
            col3 (24 * 116)
            ...
        row2...
```

I want to give them a texture, but I don't know how big the image file should be. And the box node's size seems to be relative to its parent node. How can I get the absolute size of an `SKNode`, the size the node takes on the screen?

Comment: Show the exact code that re-create the issue. You can solve this with a simple math, but without a real code, we don't know the real situation.

Comment: as I keep reading this question, I keep telling my self that I do not think you understand how SpriteKit works.  In SpriteKit, you never need to worry about the screen size (with the exception of aspect ratio),  you only worry about the scene size.  SpriteKit automatically scales based on the scalemode you chose

Comment: For all if your columns,  your textures should be 24x116, and then you let the system scale it for you

Comment: So the images could just be 24 * 116 and they will not be stretched?

Comment: they will "stretch" because the entire scene will stretch, but individually no they will not stretch

Comment: If you need pixel perfect graphics, then you need to use the `.resize` scale mode, and you may have to make a scene per device

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All SKNodes have a method called `calculateAccumulatedFrame`

Comment: That method returns 24 * 116, which was the relative size of the column nodes.

Comment: you use it on the parent/root,  `self.parent.calculateAccumulatedFrame`

Answer (score 0):

Any texture will be scaled to fill the Node. Just make sure the aspect ratio of the texture and the node are the same (e.g. make them both square).

The "size" property of a Node works! For example:

```
let test = SKSpriteNode(color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
print(test.size)
test.setScale(2.0)
print(test.size)
```

correctly prints:

```
(100.0, 100.0)
(200.0, 200.0)
```

Comment: That is a property of `SKSpriteNode`, not `SKNode`